# Apache detected external loop redirection with target URL after .htaccess setup

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've played around with this for hours, trying to get it right. It seems to be working the way I want, but I'm getting this Apache error.

I want to set it up so if someone visits my main URL they're directed to https and www, so I have this in the htaccess file in the main public_html directory.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Next I want anyone who hits subdomain.domain.com or domain.com/subdomainname to redirect to https://subdomain.domain.com, so I have this in the .htaccess file in the subdomain folder.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.subdomain\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/subdomain\.domain\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

Any hints as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your subdomain .htaccess by this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=subdomain.domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://subdomain.domain.com/$1 [R=302,NE,L]
```

Comment: Awesome, almost there! The only thing that isn't working now is when someone hits www.domain.com/subdomainfolder it goes to https://subdomain.domain.com/subdomainfolder. Any way to make it just go to https://subdomain.domain.com?